# Instagram load more button not working

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#more').click(function() {
        var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
            maxid = $(this).data('maxid'),

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'pagination.php',
          data: {
            "tag=" +tag,
            "max_id=" +maxid
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            // Output data
            $.each(data.images, function(i, img) {
  $('ul#photos').append('<li><img src="' + img.standard_resolution.url + '"></li>');
});

            // Store new maxid
            $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


 <?php
      /**
       * Instagram PHP API
       */

        require_once 'Instagram.php';
          use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;



        // Initialize class with client_id
        // Register at http://instagram.com/developer/ and replace client_id with your own
        $instagram = new Instagram('xxxxxxxx');

        // $geo = $instagram->searchMedia(56.8770413, 14.8092744);

        $tag = 'malaysia';

        // Get recently tagged media
        $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);

        // Display first results in a <ul>
        echo '<ul id="photos">';

        foreach ($media->data as $data) 
        {
            echo '<li><img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'"></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        // Show 'load more' button
        echo '<br><button id="more" name="max_id" data-maxid="'.$media->pagination->next_max_id.'" data-tag="'.$tag.'">Load more ...</button>';
    ?>
```

The above code is the index.php code where the site to show the picture and where the load more button function.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Instagram PHP API
     */
      set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
      require_once 'Instagram.php';
      use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

      // Initialize class for public requests
      $instagram = new Instagram('xxxxxxx');

      // Receive AJAX request and create call object
      $tag = $_GET['tag'];
      $maxID = $_GET['max_id'];
      $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

      $call = new stdClass();
      $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
      $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_tag_id={$maxID}";

      // Receive new data
      $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag,$auth=false,array('max_tag_id'=>$maxID));

      // Collect everything for json output
      $images = array();
      foreach ($media->data as $data) {
        $images[] = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
      }

      echo json_encode(array(
        'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
        'images'  => $images
      ));
?>
```

this part of code is the pagination.php part where the code for getting the max_id and those stuff and to run the load more button script. The problem I am having is actually when I run the code the index.php part did show images but when I run the load more button it doesn't work and when I go to pagination.php I got this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: tag in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 13

    Notice: Undefined index: max_id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 14

    Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 18

    Notice: Undefined index: X-Ratelimit-Remaining in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/Instagram.php on line 633

    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 26

    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 26

    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 31

    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 31
    {"next_id":null,"images":[]}
```

can you guys help me out pls your help will be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
    var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
        maxid = $(this).data('maxid'),
```

should be:

```
    var tag   = $(this).data('tag'),
        maxid = $(this).data('maxid');
```

(with a `;` at the end, not a `,`).

This part:

```
      data: {
        "tag=" +tag,
        "max_id=" +maxid
      },
```

Should be replaced with:

```
      data: {
        "tag": tag,
        "max_id": maxid
      },
```

(the previous syntax was just meaningless).

Comment: And what happens exactly? Are you getting the same errors, or something else? If so, what? Can you log the contents of $_GET?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on load.php line 13 the .ajax({ part

Comment: You also have a `,` to replace with a `;`, see edited answer.

Comment: Log the contents of `$_GET`.

Comment: you mean the pagination.php part?

Comment: Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: X-Ratelimit-Remaining in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/Instagram.php on line 633

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instagram search/pagination.php on line 26

Comment: this is the content as same as the error that i posted up there

Comment: No, as you can see, two of the errors are now gone.

Comment: no is still the same is still remain all the error bcz i had not enough space to put all the comments

Comment: Then log the contents of `$_GET`, as already asked for twice.